# Yahoo API into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, parsing, yahoo-finance

I am trying to pull stock data from yahoo and put it into a pandas dataframe.  If I put the api call into a web browswer I return results ... so I think the API still works but I don't know how to get it into pandas.

Thx

input

```
import pandas as pd
api = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/AAPL?interval=5m' 
df = pd.read_csv(api, skiprows=8, header=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think yahoo finance already shutdown api service to prevent data abuse ,a valid token is required to initiate data transfer,you need to exlplore other services provider like alpha
vantage as alternative
https://www.alphavantage.co/